# How can I install simplejson on hosts without root or yum, using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to install simplejson on the hosts on which I want to run my playbook.
I don't have root access to those servers, I can't `yum install` anything.

Running this ignores the first module defined in the command:

`ansible all -i hosts.ini -u dtoma -m copy -a "src=simplejson-3.8.0.tar.gz dest=~/simplejson.tgz" -m raw`

Is it possible at all to use two modules in one ansible command?

My version of ansible is:

`$ ansible --version
ansible 1.8.2
  configured module search path = None`

I could write a script to do this but I wanted to try using Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible at all to use two modules in one ansible command?

The ansible command is used to invoke a single module.  Most people use it mainly for testing purposes.

If you need to bootstrap installing python-json, and can't do it via yum, etc. then you probably need to manually copy the tarball over via scp first, then do something like:

```
$ ansible all -i hosts.ini -u dtoma -m raw -a "tar xzf simplejson.tgz ; cd simplejson ; python setup.py install"
```